assertion `left == right` failed: Bank snapshot genesis creation time does not match genesis.bin creation time
I am setting up solana-test-validator using the ledger
http://160.202.128.9:8899/snapshot-294878673-a6AxTznrH1mgMp6UhcP8Y7x4LXswTk7Grob8TFaRtSm.tar.zst
using command solana-test-validator --ledger finder/ledger/
and in this dir my tar.zst file is stored.
but after running for a while I get this error
assertion `left == right` failed: Bank snapshot genesis creation time does not match genesis.bin creation time.The snapshot and genesis.bin might pertain to different clusters
  left: 1580834132
 right: 1727439214

any help will be highly appreciated!
solana --version is solana-cli 1.18.24

The link you provide isn't available unfortunately, but the error might be telling you everything: the genesis.bin file in finder/ledger might contain the genesis file from another test cluster, and not the genesis from the cluster snapshot. Try only using what was provided in the snapshot directory, and clearing everything else.
